# Rotate the label of branch in circuitikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_1\;\; -$](4,0);
\draw (4,0)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_2\;\; -$](4,4);
\draw (4,4)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_3\;\; -$](0,4);
\draw (0,4)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_4\;\; -$](0,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

How can I rotate label v_2 and v_4? This is prefer output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really like it... ;-)

Notice that you have to use a lot of `{{{` to protect the optional argument of `rotatebox`. But I still prefer the standard voltage way...

```latex
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors, americanvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_1\;\; -$](4,0);
\draw (4,0)to [R,o-,a={{{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$+\;\; v_2\;\; -$}}}}}](4,4);
\draw (4,4)to [R,o-,a=$+\;\; v_3\;\; -$](0,4);
\draw (0,4)to [R,o-,a={{{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$+\;\; v_4\;\; -$}}}}}](0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}[voltage shift=1]
\draw (0,0)to [R,o-,v=$v_1$](3,0)
(3,0)to [R,o-,v<=$v_2$](3,3)
(3,3)to [R,o-,v>=$v_3$](0,3)
(0,3)to [R,o-,v=$v_4$](0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]